# React Native save image to specific location

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, camera-roll

I am using react native cameraroll api to save my images in storage.

```
CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(data.uri)
            .then(console.log('Success', 'Photo added to camera roll!'))
            .catch(err => console.log('err:', err))
```

Above code successfully save image in storage like (DCIM/imageName.jpg)

But i want to change the location of images to be saved somewhere else like (testfolder/1/imagename.jpg)
I tried like this:

```
CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll({
            uri: data.uri,
            album: 'test',
        }, 'photo').then((newUri) => {
            console.log('new location of image => ', newUri);
        })
```

I read this link https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/cameraroll.html#savetocameraroll but there is no proper guide or parameter set to change location.

Anyone guide me how can i change path for saving images?

Comment: anybody have solution for this?

Comment: [DIGITAL JEDI](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5088774/digital-jedi), got any answers? If yes, please share.

Answer (score 2):

As I said here : [How to save a Picture to a specific folder from React Native Camera Roll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48151242/how-to-save-a-picture-to-a-specific-folder-from-react-native-camera-roll/50081434#50081434)

**On Android**, you can use react-native-fetch-blob and its File System Access API (PictureDir constant).

```
try {
    const data = await this.camera.takePictureAsync()
    await RNFetchBlob.fs.mkdir(`${RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.PictureDir}/myfolder`)
    await RNFetchBlob.fs.mv(
        data.api, 
        `${RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.PictureDir}/myfolder/${moment().unix()}.jpg`
    )
} catch () {
    ...
}
```

https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob/wiki/File-System-Access-API

Answer (score 1):

I know that I am too late for this answer. But I got solutions without using rn-fetch-blob library.

You can simply use below npm package for get your desired output

npm i @react-native-community/cameraroll

and after that you have to use below code in try catch block so you can easily store your image on your desired path.

```
   try{
        CameraRoll.save(data.uri,{type:"photo",album:"../your folder name"}).
                    then((res)=>{console.log("save img...",res);}).
                    catch((err)=>{console.log("err for save img...",err);})
    }
    catch{
      //your code...
    }
```